# binance python library 0.7.3 gives traceback error 'endTime'; legal range

Tags: python, binance

python-binance library was working well until upgrade from 0.7 to 0.7.3. after upgrade all my scripts gives an error on this line

```
client.get_historical_klines(symbol='BTCUSDT', interval='1m', start_str="2 hour ago UTC")
```

> binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1100): Illegal
>   characters found in parameter 'endTime'; legal range is
>   '^[0-9]{1,20}$'.

i try to add other parameters like `end_str=None` but this could not fix problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in "client.py".

Download the one from the following PR and overwrite the local file.

https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/pull/415

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug. Use the earlier python-binance version 0.7.1 instead.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add further details to your answer, like which bug i.e. issue exactly and if able the part of the question triggering it.

Answer (score 1):

downgrade python-binance from 0.7.3 to 0.7.2 and restart your kernel. it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to specify a valid time for `end_str` like `end_str='now'`. If that doesn't work perhaps try passing in the integer timestamp in milliseconds:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

client.get_historical_klines(
    symbol='BTCUSDT',
    interval='1m',
    start_str=int((datetime.now() - timedelta(hours = 2)) * 1000)
    end_str=int(datetime.now() * 1000)
)
```